# Walking average based on two matching columns

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataframe `df` of the following format:

```
    team1 team2 score1 score2
0       1     2      1      0
1       3     4      3      0
2       1     3      1      1
3       2     4      0      2
4       1     2      3      2
```

What I want to do is to create a `new` column that will return rolling average of the `score1` column of last 3 games but only when the two teams from `team1` and `team2` are matching.

Expected output:

```
    team1 team2 score1 score2 new
0       1     2      1      0   1
1       3     4      3      0   3
2       1     3      1      1   1
3       2     4      0      2   0
4       1     2      3      2   2
```

I was able to calculate walking average for all games for each team separately like that:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('team1')['score1'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()
```

but cannot find a sensible way to expand that to match two teams.

I tried the code below that returns... something, but definitely not what I need.

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(['team1','team2'])['score1'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()
```

I suppose this could be done with apply() but I want to avoid it due to performace issues.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your exact expected output, but you can first reshape the DataFrame to a long format:

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), ['team', 'score'], i='index', j='x')
   .groupby('team')['score']
   .rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()
)
```

Output:

```
team  index  x
1     0      1    1.0
      2      1    1.0
2     3      1    0.0
      0      2    0.0
3     1      1    3.0
      2      2    2.0
4     1      2    0.0
      3      2    1.0
Name: score, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Indeed, I should have been more clearer. I added more information to the original question. Note rows 0 and 4 - they have matching values for 'team1' and 'team2' so the 'new' column returns walking average of these rows for 'score1'.

Comment: I'm sorry but the logic is unclear, can you break down the computation of the values in 'new'?

Comment: 1. Match only the rows where both 'team1' and 'team2' are matching.
2. Return walking average of the last 3 rows of the matching data of 'score1'.
I added a possible answer to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74459143/19135414

Answer (score 0):

The walkaround I've found was to create 'temp' column that merges the values in 'team1' and 'team2' and uses that column as a reference for the rolling average.

```
df['temp'] = df.team1+'_'+df.team2
df['new'] = df.groupby('temp')['score1'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()
```

Can this be done in one line?

Comment: I see, but then `df.groupby(['team1','team2'])['score1'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean())` should give you exactly the same thing!

Comment: Or: `df.groupby(['team1','team2'])['score1'].rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean().to_numpy()`

Comment: @mozway, yes. It does. I have no idea why it didn't work the first time I tried it... I think some variables were hanging in the memory. Thanks anyway!